# How to allocate more ram in Minecraft source code

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I'm using [MCP](http://www.modcoderpack.com/website/) with eclipse to decompile Minecraft.  I'd like to increase the amount of ram allocated to the game, but I am not sure how.

I've noticed that there is a file called `Minecraft.java` in MCP (`net.minecraft.client.Minecraft`), and I believe that I can edit that file to increase the amount of allocated ram.  I'm sure there's some obvious variable I need to change, but I wanna be sure so I don't break my client.

In `Minecraft.java`, the following array is declared:

```
/** A 10MiB preallocation to ensure the heap is reasonably sized. */
public static byte[] memoryReserve = new byte[10485760];
```

Would editing that array let me allocate more memory for general use in the game?  If not, what should I edit to increase the amount of ram (and what is the purpose of that array)?

I can't edit the amount of ram using the launcher because I'm running the game directly from MCP - **THERE IS NO LAUNCHER** at this point.  I want to increase the amount of ram in my development environment; while the launcher can be used to increase the amount of ram normally it does not help with within eclipse, where the launcher is skipped.

Comment: See the edit to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37151116/3991344).  I've edited it to give specific instructions regarding eclipse.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Braiam: I'm assuming that they want to allocate more ram for all of minecraft in general, not just that specific file.  (I'm going to edit the question under that assumption)

Answer (score 2):

No, that `memoryReserve` buffer is used for something else.  Changing it won't allow you to allocate more memory.  The point of that buffer appears to be something to free when the game runs out of memory to ensure that there *is* something that can be freed when the game runs out of memory (IE, it's reserving a bit of memory for emergencies).  Editing it won't really make a difference if you want to double the amount of RAM.

The easiest way to increase the amount of memory is to use the normal launcher to change the amount of ram.  Of course, you don't have access to the normal launcher if you're running the game from eclipse.  If you were using pure MCP and `startclient.bat`, you can edit `conf/mcp.cfg` and increase the Xmx value in `CmdStartClt` line.

However, you've mentioned that you are using eclipse, so you'll want the guide for eclipse.  The process is the same - you want to add a larger `Xmx` value; you just need to change it in a different place.

1. Select the dropdown arrow next to the run button.
   [image: Hovering over dropdown next to the green run button]
2. Select "Run Configurations..."
   [image: Run configurations button in the dropdown]
3. Switch to the arguments tab.
   [image: Circled "Arguments" tab in the "Run Configurations" screen]
4. Edit the `-Xmx` value in the "VM arguments" section.  You'll probably want to use `-Xmx2G` for 2 gigabytes, or even a larger value.  You don't need to change the other two values.
   [image: VM arguments text box in the "Arguments" tab of the "Run Configurations" screen]
5. Select "Apply" to save the changes.  You can then select "Run" to star the client, or close the Run Configurations window.  (The custom configuration will now be used when you select the normal run button - you won't need to open run configurations each time you want to start the client).
   [image: Apply and save buttons in the "Run Configurations" screen]

Comment: Great job! And that "something to free when memory runs out" trick is just crazy!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the amount of ram used from inside the code. Use the Minecraft launcher to change that.